# Avoiding server security certificate in google chrome with selenium

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, selenium

Previously I was using -trustAllSSLCertificates to surpass certificate error in google chrome with selenium rc. But after creating a firefox profile, if I use the trustAllCertificates with the profile option, firefox fails to surpass the error. If I avoid including the trustAllCertificates, google chrome fails to get past the error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused...Your subject mentions Google Chrome, not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Run `firefox.exe -profilemanager`
2. Create new profile and name it so you know whats going on - e.g. `SELENIUM`
3. In this profile, install all addons to help you bypass the certificate error
4. When creating Firefox profile do it like this:

   ```
   ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
   FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("SELENIUM");   
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
   ```

This will create Firefox browser running your profile - and should help you getting through the security warning.

I personally never tried this approach, because I did not need it, but from other SO questions and answers it seems like it could help